# How to implement caching in Blackberry?

Tags: html, caching, blackberry, browserfield

Is it really possible to cache html pages in Blackberry ?

I'm displaying web pages in BrowserField inside Blackberry application. And I want to cache the pages that has been viewed by the user, so that the next time when the user tries to open the same page, it should be loaded from the cache and not from internet.

I read that we can use **RequestListener** class for this purpose; but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Got this one - [How to cache in a Blackberry BrowserField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687200/how-to-cache-in-a-blackberry-browserfield?rq=1) Now trying this.....

Could anyone please help more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page explains the details on how to implement cache in BrowserField

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Implement-a-Web-Cache-for-Your-BrowserField2-Application/ta-p/817911